# How to test web project from eclipse to jboss as7 without mvn jboss-as:deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jboss

My firm is change the development environment, looking for some tricks and tips on how to work in the new environment.

The current environment is Eclipse and Tomcat. We are developing web applications with Spring, Web Flow, and MySQL..

The new environment is going to be Eclipse, Jboss AS7 and Maven.

**Question 1:**
Now for the questions as the current time we run tomcat on the local workstations and I can use eclipse to write my code and then just click on “Run On Server” and eclipse will build the war file and start tomcat.

With the new environment it does not look like Eclipse can start and stop and depoy right to Jboss AS so we are running a command line: mvn jboss-as:deploy does anyone know a better way?

**Question 2:**
Debugging.. Does anyone know how to get debugging working with eclipse and jboss as7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use "Run On server" with JBoss As 7 just like you do it with Tomcat. Just add new server in Eclipse for JBoss As. One difference comparing to adding new server for Tomcat is that during new server definition you should also create new runtime Environment for JBoss (if you haven't done this before) but this is very easy and intuitive. And there is a lot of examples in internet.

2) Debug is working with JBoss As very good too. If you start server from eclipse, then you can use debugger like you have used it before for Tomcat. If you run your server from command line without Eclipse, you can use remote debug from eclipse (as I remember Dubug as.. -> Remote Java Application and then specify there project, host and port).

Comment: DO YOU KNOW OF ANY GOOD WEBPAGES TO SHOW ME HOW TO DO THIS?

Comment: Here is article from JBoss As site. https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Starting+JBoss+AS+from+Eclipse+with+JBoss+Tools?_sscc=t

Comment: There are also another articles on that site where they describe in details how to start their example projects on Jboss As 7.

Comment: Examples projects you can download from their site too.